# Would it be possible to edit character models of a PS1 game, to be played on an emulator?

Tags: textures, models, blender, modding

There are some abandoned PS1 oldies out there that I would love to see revamped with improved assets. I have some skills with some some modelling programs, so I was wondering if it would be possible to rip some models with or without their textures so that I could try to update them, and experience them on an emulator. Is this possible?

Even if the edited copies cannot be reinserted into the game, would it still be possible to rip the models out so that I could edit them?

Comment: Unless you're doing this for pure experimentation, why not make a clone? The emulator is emulating hardware from ages ago.

Comment: What do you mean by "clone" in this case?